# Is there an elegant way to implement this template method- or strategy-like pattern in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am trying to decide the best way to structure some code.  I will admit this may be overboard and is turning into something more academic than practical.  Sometimes you just cannot help yourself.

Let me contrive a simple example:

Suppose you have classes/interfaces such as:

```
interface IProcessedPhoto { }

interface IPhotoProcessor
{
    IProcessedPhoto Process(byte[] bytes);
    void Alter(IProcessedPhoto processedPhoto);
}

class PhotoProcessedWithAMethod : IProcessedPhoto { }

class PhotoProcessedWithBMethod : IProcessedPhoto { }

class AProcessor : IPhotoProcessor
{ 
    IProcessedPhoto Process(byte[] bytes);  // Returns PhotoProcessedWithAMethod 
    void Alter(IProcessedPhoto processedPhoto)
    {
        var casted = processedPhoto as PhotoProcessedWithAMethod;
        // a "B" would crash here.
    }
}

class BProcessor : IPhotoProcessor
{ 
    IProcessedPhoto Process(byte[] bytes);  // Returns PhotoProcessedWithBMethod  
    void Alter(IProcessedPhoto processedPhoto)
    {
        var casted = processedPhoto as PhotoProcessedWithBMethod;
        // an "A" would crash here.
    }
}

class Algorithm
{
    void DoStuff()
    {
        var processor = ProcessorFactory.CreateProcessor(//stuff);
        var processedPhoto = processor.ProcessPhoto(new byte[100]);
        processor.Alter(processedPhoto);
    }
}
```

So basically I want the DoStuff() method to create one kind of image processor, and call the appropriate Process method.  However, despite what the interface suggests, Process only works on an IProcessedPhoto of the appropriate type (A and B photos are NOT interchangeable, they just have similar method names).  My real code is more complicated in that each processor has several classes specific to them and not interchangeable, but I want to perform the same set of "logical" operations like a template method.

```
var artifactA = processor.DoA();
var artifactB = processor.DoB();
var final = processor.Process(artifactA, artifactB);
```

I hope that explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics to bind the specific implementation of `IProcessedPhoto` to your `IPhotoProcessor`s:

```
interface IPhotoProcessor<TProcessedPhoto> 
  where TProcessedPhoto: IProcessedPhoto {

  TProcessedPhoto Process(byte[] bytes);
  void Alter(TProcessedPhoto processedPhoto);

}

...

class AProcessor : IPhotoProcessor<PhotoProcessedWithAMethod> { ... }

class BProcessor : IPhotoProcessor<PhotoProcessedWithBMethod> { ... }
```

The downside is that your factory also needs this information:

```
ProcessorFactory.CreateProcessor<PhotoProcessedWithAMethod>(/*stuff*/);
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this path.  The one thing I do not like about it (which you point out I think) is that the objects returned by CreateProcessor do not have a common ancestor besides object.  I could not write code that works with either As or Bs (but not both simultaneosly) without casting to something more generic, in which case I am back where I started.

Comment: You can return a `IPhotoProcessor<TProcessedPhoto>` from your factory. But the factory method itself needs that type parameter; which forces the client to know which value to use for the type parameter. A better approach would be to encapsulate the whole interaction in another object, and the client wouldn't need to worry about the return value from the `Process` method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your `IProcessedPhoto`/`IPhotoProcessor` abstraction is too generalized, at least for the purposes you describe.

You could create derived interfaces for each of the photo classes and processors (e.g. `IProcessedPhotoA`/`IPhotoProcessorA`, and same for `B`), and adjust your code so that only those photos that implement the required interface (`A` or `B`) are passed to a given processor.

I'm not sure whether that's the best solution for your entire codebase (which I can't see). My suggestion is based on this bit of your post:

> However, despite what the interface suggests, Process only works on an IProcessedPhoto of the appropriate type (A and B photos are NOT interchangeable, they just have similar method names)

If they're not interchangeable for the purpose of being used by a `PhotoProcessor`, your code shouldn't treat them as such.

Comment: I agree with that last bit - in fact it is the main reason I do not like the code as written.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to adjust this solution to my code to see if it works.  Like you said, not sure if the added complexity of the real code makes this work out best or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to put the Alter method on the IProcessedPhoto interface, then return an implementation that can correctly alter the processed photo.  Note you could connect it to the processor as well and use methods from it if needed (not shown).

```
public enum PhotoProcessingMethod { A, B }

public interface IProcessedPhoto
{
     void Alter();
}

public AProcessedPhoto : IProcessedPhoto
{
     ...

     public void Alter()
     {
        ... alter an A...
     }
}

public BProcessedPhoto : IProcessedPhoto
{
     ...
     public void Alter()
     {
      ... alter a B...
    }
}

public interface IPhotoProcessor
{
     IProcessedPhoto Process(byte[] bytes, PhotoProcessingMethod method);
}

public class PhotoProcessor : IPhotoProcessor
{
     public IProcessedPhoto Process(byte[] bytes, PhotoProcessingMethod method)
     {
          IProcessedPhoto photo;
          switch (method)
          {
              case PhotoProcessingMethod.A:
                   photo = new AProcessedPhoto(bytes);
                   break;
              case PhotoProcessingMethod.B:
                   photo = new BProcessedPhoto(bytes);
                   break;
          }
          ...

          return photo;
     }
}
```

Used as:

```
var processor = new PhotoProcessor();
var photoA = processor.Process( bytes, PhotoProcessingMethod.A );
photoA.Alter();
```